# MapKit, Set current location manually ? It is possible?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

How to display current location from coordinates manually? I am taking coordinates from another GPS device. How to set it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Where the coordinates come from is largely immaterial: as long as you have one you can set the map to display an area including that point.  If you want to display the point itself you can add an annotation:

A simple example method to drop a pin and zoom in to its location:

```
func createAnnotation(from coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) -> MKPointAnnotation {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    annotation.title = title
   return annotation
   }

func dropPinAndZoomIn(to coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    var spanDelta = 0.035 //the width/height of the map area in degrees
    let annotation = createAnnotation(from: coordinate, title: "My Location")
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations) //clear any prev annotations
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: spanDelta, longitudeDelta: spanDelta)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
    let displayRegion = mapView.regionThatFits(region) //ensure the region can be displayed in the mapView's view
     mapView.setRegion(displayRegion, animated: true)
}
```